# when i try to execute shell script using curl,i am getting error 403 error

Tags: bash, shell, curl, grafana

when i am try to execute below script i am getting 403 Forbidden

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
user="user5"
pass="password5"
email="user5@user.com"
user_data()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
  "name":"$user",
  "email":"$email",
  "login":"$user",
  "password":"$pass"
}
EOF
}
curl -i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-X POST http://admin:admin@10.10.34.5:32456/api/admin/users
```

i am getting below error

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: grafana_sess=f65cc6d3c6d; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 07:53:12 GMT
Content-Length: 31
```

why i am getting this error ?

Comment: I'd suggest checking your credentials.

Comment: credentials are fine, i am able to login from webUI using same credentails

Comment: What do your log files say?

Comment: Where do you use `user_data()`? Also, maybe you're missing `Host` header.

Comment: if i doesn't use user_data( ), in out put we will see the variables details, PFB 
{
  "name":"user5",
  "email":"user5@user.com",
  "login":"user5",
  "password":"password5"
}
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: grafana_sess=3cd8e7d216ab228b; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 10:02:38 GMT
Content-Length: 31

{"message":"Permission denied"}